# Solaris 11 cannot install zones

Tags: solaris, zone

Hi all staff today I try to create zone on Oracle solaris 11 but when I use command:

"zoneadm -z testzone install" and get Error

Checkpoint execution error:

```
            The following pattern(s) did not match any allowable packages.  Try
            using a different matching pattern, or refreshing publisher information:

                    pkg:///entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.0.6.0.6.0:20120410T204143Z
```

Installation: Failed.  See install log at /system/volatile/install.4373/install_log
ERROR: auto-install failed.

Any one can help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a know bug fixed in SRU 7:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2380689

Comment: Hi jlliagre I cannot access to above forum, How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Install SRU 7. Have a look to the "Installing Maintenance Updates on an Oracle Solaris 11 System" chapter in  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/gljrq.html